# How can a class inherit from Object class and another explicit super class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I know that Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. Every class in Java inherits from `java.lang.Object` class. In the absence of any other explicit super class, every class is implicitly a subclass of `java.lang.Object` class.

So how is it possible for a class to inherit from `java.lang.Object` and another explicit super class when Java doesn't support multiple inheritance?

For example

```
class MySuperClass {
 //this is the explicit super class
}
class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {
// this is the subclass
}
```

How can `MySubClass` inherit from `java.lang.Object` and `MySuperClass` when Java doesn't support multiple inheritance?

Comment: not alloweing multiple inheritance means you cannot do `class A extends B, C`. `class A extends B` and `class B extends C` is however totally fine. Thats just hierarchical inheritance not multiple inheritance.

Comment: Think of it a bit like this: You can inherit the looks of your father - and also the looks of your grandfather (as that is via your father). But that isn't multiple inheritance. However, you *cannot* also inherit the look of the guy across the road as that **would** be multiple inheritance.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A extends B.

B extends C.

So A extends C implicitly. Rename C to Object and the puzzle is solved. That is how any class is in the end derived from Object.

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself, in Java all class inherit from

> java.lang.Object

Therefore your superclass (MySuperClass) inherit from it and so does your subclass
(MySubClass)

```
Object <-- MySuperClass <-- MySubClass
```

Not allowing multi-inheritance is another concept like having

```
MySubClass extends MySuperClassA, MySuperClassB
```

In Java this will be done through interfaces!!